# Using specific keys of python dictionary to plot a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

Is there some way to use specific keys of python dictionary to plot a graph?

```
{'iso_code': array(['AFG', 'OWID_AFR', 'ALB', 'DZA', 'AND', 'AGO', 'AIA', 'ATG', 'ARG',
       'ARM', 'OWID_ASI', 'AUS', 'AUT', 'AZE', 'BHS', 'BHR', 'BGD', 'BRB',
       'BLR', 'BEL', 'BLZ', 'BEN', 'BMU', 'BTN', 'BOL', 'BIH', 'BWA',
       'BRA', 'BRN', 'BGR', 'BFA', 'BDI', 'KHM', 'CMR', 'CAN', 'CPV',
       'CYM', 'CAF', 'TCD', 'CHL', 'CHN', 'COL', 'COM', 'COG', 'CRI',
       'CIV', 'HRV', 'CUB', 'CYP', 'CZE', 'COD', 'DNK', 'DJI', 'DMA',
       'DOM', 'ECU', 'EGY', 'SLV', 'GNQ', 'ERI', 'EST', 'SWZ', 'ETH',
       'OWID_EUR', 'OWID_EUN', 'FRO', 'FLK', 'FJI', 'FIN', 'FRA', 'GAB',
       'GMB', 'GEO', 'DEU', 'GHA', 'GIB', 'GRC', 'GRL', 'GRD', 'GTM',
       'GGY', 'GIN', 'GNB', 'GUY', 'HTI', 'HND', 'HKG', 'HUN', 'ISL',
       'IND', 'IDN', 'OWID_INT', 'IRN', 'IRQ', 'IRL', 'IMN', 'ISR', 'ITA',
       'JAM', 'JPN', 'JEY', 'JOR', 'KAZ', 'KEN', 'OWID_KOS', 'KWT', 'KGZ',
       'LAO', 'LVA', 'LBN', 'LSO', 'LBR', 'LBY', 'LIE', 'LTU', 'LUX',
       'MAC', 'MDG', 'MWI', 'MYS', 'MDV', 'MLI', 'MLT', 'MHL', 'MRT',
       'MUS', 'MEX', 'FSM', 'MDA', 'MCO', 'MNG', 'MNE', 'MSR', 'MAR',
       'MOZ', 'MMR', 'NAM', 'NPL', 'NLD', 'NZL', 'NIC', 'NER', 'NGA',
       'OWID_NAM', 'MKD', 'OWID_CYN', 'NOR', 'OWID_OCE', 'OMN', 'PAK',
       'PSE', 'PAN', 'PNG', 'PRY', 'PER', 'PHL', 'POL', 'PRT', 'QAT',
       'ROU', 'RUS', 'RWA', 'SHN', 'KNA', 'LCA', 'VCT', 'WSM', 'SMR',
       'STP', 'SAU', 'SEN', 'SRB', 'SYC', 'SLE', 'SGP', 'SVK', 'SVN',
       'SLB', 'SOM', 'ZAF', 'OWID_SAM', 'KOR', 'SSD', 'ESP', 'LKA', 'SDN',
       'SUR', 'SWE', 'CHE', 'SYR', 'TWN', 'TJK', 'TZA', 'THA', 'TLS',
       'TGO', 'TTO', 'TUN', 'TUR', 'TCA', 'UGA', 'UKR', 'ARE', 'GBR',
       'USA', 'URY', 'UZB', 'VUT', 'VAT', 'VEN', 'VNM', 'OWID_WRL', 'YEM',
       'ZMB', 'ZWE'], dtype='<U8'), 'total_cases_per_million': array([1.43535500e+03, 2.96969000e+03, 3.96862190e+04, 2.61209300e+03,
       1.43519058e+05, 6.42422000e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 8.80238500e+03,
       4.78363500e+04, 5.91239170e+04, 5.54501300e+03, 1.14016200e+03,
       5.32278160e+04, 2.34003260e+04, 2.19759540e+04, 7.51065330e+04,
       3.35229300e+03, 1.15982480e+04, 3.14852250e+04, 6.82655060e+04,
       3.10471530e+04, 5.22799000e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 1.12491800e+03,
       2.18984290e+04, 4.22279220e+04, 1.39954290e+04, 5.23262130e+04,
       4.36588000e+02, 3.83978000e+04, 5.83019000e+02, 1.96707000e+02,
       6.72290000e+01, 1.38605400e+03, 2.38241550e+04, 2.84646430e+04,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.04000900e+03, 2.56547000e+02, 4.52005940e+04,
       7.02930000e+01, 4.48553980e+04, 4.14675800e+03, 1.66343700e+03,
       4.07984590e+04, 1.34493300e+03, 6.01907110e+04, 5.08598500e+03,
       4.29844080e+04, 1.24737814e+05, 2.97941000e+02, 3.73747260e+04,
       6.25606000e+03, 2.09748400e+03, 2.24723600e+04, 1.67269170e+04,
       1.83433900e+03, 9.48768000e+03, 4.54103200e+03, 8.30131000e+02,
       5.84159230e+04, 1.48177330e+04, 1.46424600e+03, 4.75039360e+04,
       5.25902800e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 7.36240000e+01,
       1.13902210e+04, 5.85897360e+04, 7.19539900e+03, 1.98289900e+03,
       6.84695460e+04, 3.00847380e+04, 2.79139900e+03, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.00960260e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 1.31533300e+03, 1.00227360e+04,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.28776900e+03, 1.68648500e+03, 1.12477260e+04,
       1.09940500e+03, 1.76188700e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 4.91914890e+04,
       1.77787550e+04, 8.16135600e+03, 5.09259500e+03, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.03178830e+04, 1.82889170e+04, 4.53556610e+04, 0.00000000e+00,
       9.33808760e+04, 5.12900970e+04, 9.27507800e+03, 3.48801700e+03,
       0.00000000e+00, 4.33397950e+04, 1.43581620e+04, 2.03906200e+03,
       3.81498300e+04, 4.75475950e+04, 1.32798070e+04, 6.46000000e+00,
       4.82435070e+04, 5.88717920e+04, 4.91305400e+03, 4.00579000e+02,
       2.04747670e+04, 6.80179350e+04, 7.45328110e+04, 9.07734480e+04,
       0.00000000e+00, 7.27853000e+02, 1.70037000e+03, 9.77164400e+03,
       3.89127950e+04, 4.25316000e+02, 5.62736250e+04, 6.75740000e+01,
       3.73468200e+03, 5.04023000e+02, 1.65813880e+04, 8.69400000e+00,
       4.87052060e+04, 5.21863210e+04, 1.06183300e+03, 1.28654496e+05,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.31895320e+04, 2.01187400e+03, 2.61090900e+03,
       1.58749840e+04, 9.43373800e+03, 6.67341390e+04, 4.99768000e+02,
       9.86783000e+02, 1.99739000e+02, 7.72544000e+02, 5.66814130e+04,
       5.20068350e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 1.41082060e+04, 7.80734000e+02,
       2.83614100e+04, 2.69470200e+03, 3.92796820e+04, 8.01338570e+04,
       1.94590000e+02, 2.41127620e+04, 4.18545870e+04, 5.47930300e+03,
       4.78520070e+04, 7.95654910e+04, 5.82729970e+04, 4.34330910e+04,
       2.94224540e+04, 1.52707500e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 7.70793000e+02,
       2.12493670e+04, 1.49891390e+04, 1.51200000e+01, 1.17390536e+05,
       9.02076600e+03, 1.09316210e+04, 2.15236200e+03, 7.26135690e+04,
       3.08318080e+04, 4.91664000e+02, 1.02646970e+04, 5.97095820e+04,
       9.44816860e+04, 2.62060000e+01, 5.39664000e+02, 2.56740960e+04,
       4.35516270e+04, 1.82825200e+03, 7.92408000e+02, 6.76932240e+04,
       4.03222300e+03, 6.99806000e+02, 1.53161940e+04, 6.89133970e+04,
       6.54462160e+04, 9.20937000e+02, 4.10220000e+01, 1.39531300e+03,
       8.52100000e+00, 3.79671000e+02, 1.07703000e+02, 9.27678000e+02,
       5.52772400e+03, 2.01895860e+04, 3.32869110e+04, 0.00000000e+00,
       8.85201000e+02, 3.33560400e+04, 4.20311620e+04, 6.24850150e+04,
       8.81155580e+04, 1.88636010e+04, 2.39763700e+03, 9.76700000e+00,
       3.33745360e+04, 5.04013500e+03, 2.59510000e+01, 1.50906070e+04,
       8.67030000e+01, 4.50920400e+03, 2.44373100e+03]), 'total_deaths_per_million': array([6.296200e+01, 7.935300e+01, 6.842030e+02, 6.891500e+01,
       1.449557e+03, 1.570000e+01, 0.000000e+00, 2.246550e+02,
       1.178252e+03, 1.090700e+03, 8.751800e+01, 3.564700e+01,
       9.723090e+02, 3.205390e+02, 4.704410e+02, 2.785640e+02,
       5.154600e+01, 1.287530e+02, 2.174760e+02, 1.926466e+03,
       7.947270e+02, 6.681000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.296000e+00,
       1.015846e+03, 1.629168e+03, 1.756230e+02, 1.262565e+03,
       6.857000e+00, 1.568984e+03, 6.841000e+00, 2.520000e-01,
       0.000000e+00, 2.132200e+01, 5.909040e+02, 2.769840e+02,
       0.000000e+00, 1.304400e+01, 9.010000e+00, 1.108065e+03,
       3.361000e+00, 1.192464e+03, 1.678940e+02, 2.374000e+01,
       5.590770e+02, 7.809000e+00, 1.369216e+03, 3.107700e+01,
       2.660120e+02, 2.068077e+03, 7.950000e+00, 4.112420e+02,
       6.376500e+01, 0.000000e+00, 2.941580e+02, 9.107830e+02,
       1.082920e+02, 2.964760e+02, 6.842600e+01, 1.974000e+00,
       5.043200e+02, 5.671610e+02, 2.132000e+01, 1.125864e+03,
       1.271643e+03, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 2.231000e+00,
       1.400540e+02, 1.312664e+03, 4.088500e+01, 6.331000e+01,
       9.026930e+02, 8.657270e+02, 2.111200e+01, 0.000000e+00,
       6.565250e+02, 0.000000e+00, 8.887000e+00, 3.624220e+02,
       0.000000e+00, 7.386000e+00, 2.489800e+01, 2.593580e+02,
       2.201300e+01, 4.338380e+02, 0.000000e+00, 1.671368e+03,
       8.498200e+01, 1.145380e+02, 1.380390e+02, 0.000000e+00,
       7.246680e+02, 3.385670e+02, 9.016170e+02, 0.000000e+00,
       6.854570e+02, 1.661858e+03, 1.553440e+02, 6.609100e+01,
       0.000000e+00, 4.945540e+02, 1.697320e+02, 3.507400e+01,
       8.562820e+02, 2.671780e+02, 2.262350e+02, 0.000000e+00,
       9.039330e+02, 7.521860e+02, 1.442410e+02, 1.680600e+01,
       3.342900e+02, 1.442169e+03, 1.227275e+03, 1.067134e+03,
       0.000000e+00, 1.083400e+01, 5.614200e+01, 3.664300e+01,
       1.184000e+02, 1.767800e+01, 7.587100e+02, 0.000000e+00,
       9.506100e+01, 7.863000e+00, 1.487512e+03, 0.000000e+00,
       1.028765e+03, 6.625220e+02, 9.150000e-01, 1.738682e+03,
       0.000000e+00, 2.355690e+02, 2.239600e+01, 5.881300e+01,
       1.747400e+02, 1.033740e+02, 9.364530e+02, 5.392000e+00,
       2.641700e+01, 7.312000e+00, 9.644000e+00, 1.299588e+03,
       1.549405e+03, 0.000000e+00, 1.165780e+02, 2.233000e+01,
       3.127310e+02, 6.031900e+01, 4.253720e+02, 1.377594e+03,
       1.788000e+00, 4.710810e+02, 1.460731e+03, 1.143260e+02,
       1.204837e+03, 1.627486e+03, 9.163300e+01, 1.094519e+03,
       6.051690e+02, 2.084600e+01, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00,
       2.505050e+02, 7.210700e+01, 0.000000e+00, 2.268843e+03,
       1.460110e+02, 1.878270e+02, 5.554300e+01, 6.758670e+02,
       1.525320e+02, 9.903000e+00, 4.957000e+00, 1.472074e+03,
       1.877887e+03, 0.000000e+00, 2.007100e+01, 8.583230e+02,
       1.126786e+03, 3.214400e+01, 9.112000e+00, 1.534110e+03,
       2.386400e+01, 4.367200e+01, 2.983120e+02, 1.291380e+03,
       1.162963e+03, 6.136900e+01, 4.200000e-01, 9.436000e+00,
       3.520000e-01, 1.218000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.111300e+01,
       1.000360e+02, 6.995740e+02, 3.457470e+02, 0.000000e+00,
       7.302000e+00, 6.561980e+02, 1.359900e+02, 1.841793e+03,
       1.597178e+03, 1.917250e+02, 1.858400e+01, 0.000000e+00,
       0.000000e+00, 4.919800e+01, 3.600000e-01, 3.349870e+02,
       2.192700e+01, 6.184700e+01, 1.001820e+02]), 'population': array([  38928341, 1340598113,    2877800,   43851043,      77265,
         32866268,      15002,      97928,   45195777,    2963234,
       4639847425,   25499881,    9006400,   10139175,     393248,
          1701583,  164689383,     287371,    9449321,   11589616,
           397621,   12123198,      62273,     771612,   11673029,
          3280815,    2351625,  212559409,     437483,    6948445,
         20903278,   11890781,   16718971,   26545864,   37742157,
           555988,      65720,    4829764,   16425859,   19116209,
       1439323774,   50882884,     869595,    5518092,    5094114,
         26378275,    4105268,   11326616,     875899,   10708982,
         89561404,    5792203,     988002,      71991,   10847904,
         17643060,  102334403,    6486201,    1402985,    3546427,
          1326539,    1160164,  114963583,  748680069,  444919060,
            48865,       3483,     896444,    5540718,   68147687,
          2225728,    2416664,    3989175,   83783945,   31072945,
            33691,   10423056,      56772,     112519,   17915567,
            67052,   13132792,    1967998,     786559,   11402533,
          9904608,    7496988,    9660350,     341250, 1380004385,
        273523621,          0,   83992953,   40222503,    4937796,
            85032,    8655541,   60461828,    2961161,  126476458,
           101073,   10203140,   18776707,   53771300,    1932774,
          4270563,    6524191,    7275556,    1886202,    6825442,
          2142252,    5057677,    6871287,      38137,    2722291,
           625976,     649342,   27691019,   19129955,   32365998,
           540542,   20250834,     441539,      59194,    4649660,
          1271767,  128932753,     115021,    4033963,      39244,
          3278292,     628062,       4999,   36910558,   31255435,
         54409794,    2540916,   29136808,   17134873,    4822233,
          6624554,   24206636,  206139587,  592072204,    2083380,
                0,    5421242,   42677809,    5106622,  220892331,
          5101416,    4314768,    8947027,    7132530,   32971846,
        109581085,   37846605,   10196707,    2881060,   19237682,
        145934460,   12952209,       6071,      53192,     183629,
           110947,     198410,      33938,     219161,   34813867,
         16743930,    6804596,      98340,    7976985,    5850343,
          5459643,    2078932,     686878,   15893219,   59308690,
        430759772,   51269183,   11193729,   46754783,   21413250,
         43849269,     586634,   10099270,    8654618,   17500657,
         23816775,    9537642,   59734213,   69799978,    1318442,
          8278737,    1399491,   11818618,   84339067,      38718,
         45741000,   43733759,    9890400,   67886004,  331002647,
          3473727,   33469199,     307150,        809,   28435943,
         97338583, 7794798729,   29825968,   18383956,   14862927]), 'population_density': array([5.4422000e+01, 0.0000000e+00, 1.0487100e+02, 1.7348000e+01,
       1.6375500e+02, 2.3890000e+01, 0.0000000e+00, 2.3184500e+02,
       1.6177000e+01, 1.0293100e+02, 0.0000000e+00, 3.2020000e+00,
       1.0674900e+02, 1.1930900e+02, 3.9497000e+01, 1.9359070e+03,
       1.2650360e+03, 6.6446300e+02, 4.6858000e+01, 3.7556400e+02,
       1.6426000e+01, 9.9110000e+01, 1.3088200e+03, 2.1188000e+01,
       1.0202000e+01, 6.8496000e+01, 4.0440000e+00, 2.5040000e+01,
       8.1347000e+01, 6.5180000e+01, 7.0151000e+01, 4.2306200e+02,
       9.0672000e+01, 5.0885000e+01, 4.0370000e+00, 1.3558000e+02,
       2.5649600e+02, 7.4790000e+00, 1.1833000e+01, 2.4282000e+01,
       1.4767400e+02, 4.4223000e+01, 4.3735200e+02, 1.5405000e+01,
       9.6079000e+01, 7.6399000e+01, 7.3726000e+01, 1.1040800e+02,
       1.2765700e+02, 1.3717600e+02, 3.5879000e+01, 1.3652000e+02,
       4.1285000e+01, 9.8567000e+01, 2.2287300e+02, 6.6939000e+01,
       9.7999000e+01, 3.0781100e+02, 4.5194000e+01, 4.4304000e+01,
       3.1033000e+01, 7.9492000e+01, 1.0495700e+02, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 3.5308000e+01, 0.0000000e+00, 4.9562000e+01,
       1.8136000e+01, 1.2257800e+02, 7.8590000e+00, 2.0756600e+02,
       6.5032000e+01, 2.3701600e+02, 1.2671900e+02, 3.4571000e+03,
       8.3479000e+01, 1.3700000e-01, 3.1713200e+02, 1.5783400e+02,
       0.0000000e+00, 5.1755000e+01, 6.6191000e+01, 3.9520000e+00,
       3.9844800e+02, 8.2805000e+01, 7.0397140e+03, 1.0804300e+02,
       3.4040000e+00, 4.5041900e+02, 1.4572500e+02, 0.0000000e+00,
       4.9831000e+01, 8.8125000e+01, 6.9874000e+01, 1.4787200e+02,
       4.0260600e+02, 2.0585900e+02, 2.6687900e+02, 3.4777800e+02,
       0.0000000e+00, 1.0928500e+02, 6.6810000e+00, 8.7324000e+01,
       1.6815500e+02, 2.3212800e+02, 3.2333000e+01, 2.9715000e+01,
       3.1212000e+01, 5.9456100e+02, 7.3562000e+01, 4.9127000e+01,
       3.6230000e+00, 2.3701200e+02, 4.5135000e+01, 2.3144700e+02,
       2.0546766e+04, 4.3951000e+01, 1.9751900e+02, 9.6254000e+01,
       1.4544330e+03, 1.5196000e+01, 1.4540370e+03, 2.9515000e+02,
       4.2890000e+00, 6.2296200e+02, 6.6444000e+01, 1.5077700e+02,
       1.2365500e+02, 1.9347500e+04, 1.9800000e+00, 4.6280000e+01,
       0.0000000e+00, 8.0080000e+01, 3.7728000e+01, 8.1721000e+01,
       3.0780000e+00, 2.0443000e+02, 5.0854400e+02, 1.8206000e+01,
       5.1667000e+01, 1.6955000e+01, 2.0958800e+02, 0.0000000e+00,
       8.2600000e+01, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4462000e+01, 0.0000000e+00,
       1.4980000e+01, 2.5557300e+02, 7.7820200e+02, 5.5133000e+01,
       1.8220000e+01, 1.7144000e+01, 2.5129000e+01, 3.5187300e+02,
       1.2402700e+02, 1.1237100e+02, 2.2732200e+02, 8.5129000e+01,
       8.8230000e+00, 4.9486900e+02, 0.0000000e+00, 2.1286500e+02,
       2.9318700e+02, 2.8178700e+02, 6.9413000e+01, 5.5666700e+02,
       2.1284100e+02, 1.5322000e+01, 8.2328000e+01, 8.0291000e+01,
       2.0835400e+02, 1.0470000e+02, 7.9157310e+03, 1.1312800e+02,
       1.0261900e+02, 2.1841000e+01, 2.3500000e+01, 4.6754000e+01,
       0.0000000e+00, 5.2796700e+02, 0.0000000e+00, 9.3105000e+01,
       3.4195500e+02, 2.3258000e+01, 3.6120000e+00, 2.4718000e+01,
       2.1424300e+02, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 6.4281000e+01,
       6.4699000e+01, 1.3513200e+02, 8.7176000e+01, 1.4336600e+02,
       2.6688600e+02, 7.4228000e+01, 1.0491400e+02, 3.7312000e+01,
       2.1375900e+02, 7.7390000e+01, 1.1244200e+02, 2.7289800e+02,
       3.5608000e+01, 1.9751000e+01, 7.6134000e+01, 2.2662000e+01,
       0.0000000e+00, 3.6253000e+01, 3.0812700e+02, 5.8045000e+01,
       5.3508000e+01, 2.2995000e+01, 4.2729000e+01])}
```

This is my dictionary. I need to plot a graph between population density and deaths per million. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

Where d is your dictionary above,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.plot.scatter(x='population_density', y='total_deaths_per_million')
```

Output:

[image]